# Countifs Property Run-time error with String Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, function, sumifs

I have not expressed `worksheetfunction.countifs` correctly.

I get:

> Run-time error '1004':
> Unable to get the CountIfs property of the WorksheetFunction Class

```vb
Sub test()
Dim Category(7 To 10) As Variant
Dim Ar As Variant
Dim Da As Range
Dim Cat As Range
Dim Br As Variant

Set Da = Range("A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set Cat = Range("C3:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Ar = Range("F2").Value2
Br = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("F2"), 0)

For i = 7 To 10
    Category(i) = Worksheets("Log").Cells(1, i).Value
    Cells(2, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Da, ">=" & Ar, Da, "<=" & Br, Cat, Category(i))
Next i

End Sub
```

It seems like the issue is with the last range and criteria on the sumifs function (the Cat,Category(i) where Category(i) is equal to a string).

If I split the sumif and use the Cat,Category on its own in a SUMIF, it works fine, and the other two criteria's work fine alone.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was actually due to the way that the string criteria was being declared, changing that fixed it.

```
Cells(2, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)), "=" & test & "*", Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)), ">=" & Ar, Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)), "<=" & Br)
```

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference, but you do need to make sure that the ranges have the same number of rows.